# How to solve real values for quadratic equations with a fractional expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, quadratics

Reference to book:
Tranter, C.J., 1971, Advanced Level Pure Mathematics. *The English Universities Press*. London. (20)

Difficulties on finding the real values for this equation:

> Show that for all real values of y ,  the expression 
>   $$ \frac{3y^2 - 2y -1 }{y^2 + y + 2}$$
>   always lie between $-4/7$ and $4$

I have tried $3y^2 -2y -1 = y^2 + y + 2$ and then combining into quadratic to form $6y^2 - 3y - 3.$

How do I express this into bracketed form?

How to find $(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)$ when $ny$ is involved in the equation?

Background:
Self-study, mainly quantitative skills in applied mathematics very little so in analysis or pure mathematics. equivalent to early A-level/mid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4-\frac{3y^2 - 2y -1 }{y^2 + y + 2}
=\frac{y^2+6y+9}{y^2 + y + 2}=\frac{(y+3)^2}{(y+1/2)^2+7/4}\ge0.$$
I'll leave you to figure out the other inequality.